# Less noisy cell buttons on a table

Tags: usability, gui-design, buttons, user-behavior, tables

I have table where almost all of its cells are a button that works independently. When I add a 3D button-like design to each cell, the table becomes a large chunk filled with buttons and looks a little noisy. Is there a way to make the table less noisy while making it clearly recognizable that the cells are buttons? Some cells are not buttons, so there has to be some difference among the cells that are buttons and those that are not.

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be a table ? I would help if you gave an example.

Comment: you could go the windows 8 route with flat square buttons

Comment: Use hyper links instead of buttons

Comment: Please share your design so that we have a better idea of what you are referring to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tables are already very heavy visually so you can add some sort of icon next to the text to indicate that it is a link. i.e.

[image: table]

The advantages of doing this are:
- The user can quickly identify which cells have buttons
- The essence of the table remains
- The visual weight will look balanced

Comment: I would add the marker before the text in the cell, since in this view it 'looks' like it is point at the adjacent cell.

Answer (score 4):

If the buttons take up the entire cell, you will reduce noise.  Granted, they will look less like buttons, but if you apply a **gradient** and **different text alignment**, it should be clear enough.  You could experiment with different fonts and font sizes too, but I'm not fond of the design results.

Here is a rough mockup of what I'm referring to:

[image]

---

I would still question whether there isn't a solution better than a table for this, but if it had to be a table, this is what I would test first.